# Storing Multiple Variables in List Based on Conditional Statement

Tags: r, for-loop

I am currently trying to store these values together in a list. I want to essentially loop through two sequences and save the occurrences where `var1` is greater than `var2`. The print statement appears to work, however, I think I am doing something wrong with saving the result in a list.

```
var1 <- seq(5, 51, by = 2)
var2 <- seq(2, 10, by = 1)
list <- list()
for (j in seq_along(var1)) {
for (i in seq_along(var2)) {
    if (var1[j] > var2[i]) {
      list[[i]] <- print(c(var1[j], var2[i]))
    }
  }
}
```

This is just an example, I am trying to use both variables to plug into a function that filters through data and provides a result. I therefore want a combination of 204 lists of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what should `list` look like at the end if everything were to work correctly?

Comment: `list` should look like the `print` statement, but each line stored within the `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be easier to store in a data.frame. YOu can more easily do this in base R with

```
expand.grid(var1=var1, var2=var2) |>
  subset(var1 >var2)
```

or with tidyverse stuff

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(var1, var2) %>% 
  filter(var1 > var2)
```

Comment: I get an error when I run that based on `|>`. Further, I'm ultimately trying to figure out a way to loop through the too sequences and perform a separate function. I was hoping to understand how I could create these lists. The `tidy verse` way also produces an error.

Comment: The `|>` was added in R 4.1. Maybe you are using an older version. Not sure what error you got on the other code. But you can easily use this output to run whatever function you want on the resulting values. It's better to avoid incrementally appending values in lists in R inside of nested loops -- repeated memory allocations can be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the update on `R`. This worked for the problem I need to develop. Although, I got the error `Error in filter.default(., window_length > polyorder) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default` when using @akrun's solution.